# Calculate average in RED SHIFT based in Calendar week

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, calculated-columns

Given the example data present in my Redshift database table, it is necessary to compute the average for each category (exam_type) according to the total weekdays specified within a given time range, The total weekdays should not be calculated in the database but rather in the calendar table. Consider I need to calculate for date range From May 1 2023 to June 30, 2023.

| exam_type | exam_date | volumes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CR | 1/1/2023 | 30 |
| CR | 3/1/2023 | 50 |
| CR | 4/1/2023 | 10 |
| CR | 5/1/2023 | 30 |
| CR | 6/1/2023 | 30 |
| CR | 7/1/2023 | 30 |
| CR | 8/1/2023 | 36 |
| CR | 9/1/2023 | 24 |
| CR | 10/1/2023 | 58 |
| CR | 12/1/2023 | 48 |
| CR | 13/1/2023 | 24 |
| CR | 14/1/2023 | 36 |

EXPECTED OUTPUT

| exam_type | Day of week | Total database days | Total calendar days | Total volumes | Calendar average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CR | Sunday | 2 | 2 | 66 | 33 |
| CR | Monday | 1 | 2 | 24 | 12 |
| CR | Tuesday | 2 | 2 | 108 | 54 |
| CR | Wednesday | 1 | 2 | 10 | 5 |
| CR | Thursday | 2 | 2 | 78 | 39 |
| CR | Friday | 2 | 2 | 54 | 27 |
| CR | Saturday | 2 | 2 | 66 | 33 |